# Python : ask the number of common word you want

Tags: python

I'm quite new with the functionnalities of Python. And I need to know if someone can help me ?

My problem is : I have to create a program where someone can tap the number of most common words he/her wants. I don't know if I'm understandable.

But for example : 
I need to use "x=input("enter a number : ")
then the user can tap one number and the program will say : "here are the x most common word in your text".

Here my program :

```
import re

from collections import Counter

words = re.findall("[a-zA-Z_]+", open("vie.txt").read()

count = Counter(words).most_common()

print(count)`
```

I know I can have the number I want by using most_common(), but I would like the program to ask it and not putting it in the code.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking to, for example, return the 5 most common words if the user enters `5`.  [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) can actually do this for you, if you pass a number to it as an argument.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

words = re.findall("[a-zA-Z_]+", open("vie.txt").read()

x = int(input('How many of the most common words would you like? '))

count = Counter(words).most_common(x)    
print(count)
```

Comment: Ohh ok! I did this before but i didn't use int! 
Thank you very much for you help!